# UICollectionView in a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am interested in having a collectionview as a part of a collection view cell but for some reason cannot figure out how this would be done. Where would I implement the necessary methods for the cells collectionview?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's [an article that Ash Furrow wrote](http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell) that explains how to put an `UICollectionView` inside an `UITableViewCell`. It's basically the same idea when using it inside an `UICollectionViewCell`.

Answer (score 11):

Everything is done programatically. No storyboards.

I added a UICollectionView inside my UICollectionViewCell. I also show how to add again a UICollectionViewCell inside the created UICollectionView to have this result

[image]

```
import UIKit

class CategoryCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    private let cellId = "cell"

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let appsCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        return collectionView
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = .blue

        addSubview(appsCollectionView)

        appsCollectionView.delegate = self
        appsCollectionView.dataSource = self
        appsCollectionView.register(AppCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        addConstrainstWithFormat("H:|-8-[v0]-8-|", views: appsCollectionView)
        addConstrainstWithFormat("V:|[v0]|", views: appsCollectionView)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}

class AppCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupViews(){
        backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

My UICollectionViewController

```
import UIKit

class FeaturedAppsController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let cellId = "cell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView?.register(CategoryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(view.frame.width, 150)
    }

}
```

The whole explanation can be found and was developed by "Let´s build that app": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ko9oNhlTwH0&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JEXct3-OV6itP7Kz3tRDmma

Comment: is there a retain cycle where you declare appsCollectionView? Do you believe its best to have it let appsCollectionView: UICollectionView = { [weak self] in ....}?

Comment: @christostsang It doesn't create a retain cycle because in the init of the collectionView we are not capturing / retaining "self".

Comment: i thought you had the collectionView.delegate = self and collectionView.datasource = self inside the self closing block! :) In that case, would that be a retain cycle in your opinion?

Comment: I don't think so because delegate and datasource are declared as "weak var".

Comment: Last question: Do you think that its best to create a different UICollectionViewController to handle that appsCollectionView, or keep it like this, the collectionView setup procedure inside the cell?

Comment: You shouldn't add a ViewController inside a class that inherits from UIView, that's why it's better to use collectionView and not a ViewController. You can have a viewController that contains other viewControllers, but that requires not only to add them in the view, but some other setup, so the things like "viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear) work correctly in the embedded viewControllers.

Answer (score 4):

This is too late for this answer but it might help others. This is an example of `UICollectionView` inside a `UICollectionViewCell`.

Lets start by having a `mainCollectionView`. Then on each cell of this collection create and initialize a new `UICollectionView` and right place to do that is in this following delegate of UICollectionView

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`

e.g I initialize the `MainCollectionViewCell` here and then `MainCollectionViewCell` handles the logic to create a new `UICollectionView`

```
guard let collectionViewCell = cell as? MainCollectionViewCell else { return }

    collectionViewCell.delegate = self

    let dataProvider = ChildCollectionViewDataSource()
    dataProvider.data = data[indexPath.row] as NSArray

    let delegate = ChildCollectionViewDelegate()

    collectionViewCell.initializeCollectionViewWithDataSource(dataProvider, delegate: delegate, forRow: indexPath.row)

    collectionViewCell.collectionViewOffset = storedOffsets[indexPath.row] ?? 0
```

Here is the initializer on `MainCollectionViewCell` that creates a new `UICollectionView`

```
func initializeCollectionViewWithDataSource<D: protocol<UICollectionViewDataSource>,E: protocol<UICollectionViewDelegate>>(dataSource: D, delegate :E, forRow row: Int) {

    self.collectionViewDataSource = dataSource

    self.collectionViewDelegate = delegate

    let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = .Horizontal

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseChildCollectionViewCellIdentifier)
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    collectionView.dataSource = self.collectionViewDataSource
    collectionView.delegate = self.collectionViewDelegate
    collectionView.tag = row

    self.addSubview(collectionView)

    self.collectionView = collectionView

    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Hope that helps !!

I did an example for this and put in on github. It demonstrates the use `UICollectionView` inside a `UICollectionViewCell`.

https://github.com/irfanlone/Collection-View-in-a-collection-view-cell

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution for collectionview inside collectionview using storyboard and Swift 5

[Please refer this link for nested collectionview example](https://github.com/bhorvinayak/NestedCollectionView)

```
import UIKit
class ParentViewController:UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {
//MARK: Declare variable

//MARK: Decalare outlet
@IBOutlet weak var outerCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!
let outerCount = 4

//MARK: Decalare life cycle methods
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pageControl.numberOfPages = outerCount
    
}
//MARK: Collection View delegate methods
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return outerCount
}
//MARK: Collection View datasource methods
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "OuterCell", for: indexPath) as! OuterCollectionViewCell
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .none
    return cell
    
}
//MARK:- For Display the page number in page controll of collection view Cell
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: self.outerCollectionView.contentOffset, size: self.outerCollectionView.bounds.size)
    let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
    if let visibleIndexPath = self.outerCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint) {
        self.pageControl.currentPage = visibleIndexPath.row
    }
}
}
class OuterCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell ,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var InnerCollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    InnerCollectionView.delegate = self
    InnerCollectionView.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    6
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "InnerCell", for: indexPath) as! InnerCollectionViewCell
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .green
    return cell
}


}
class InnerCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell{


}
```