# sizeForItemAtIndexPath and cellForItemAtIndexPath is not called

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I tried to create a UICollectionView inside a UICollectionViewCellCell, but the func sizeForItemAtIndexPath and cellForItemAtIndexPath is not called, here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class HistoryCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    static let cellId = "cell"

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpCollectionView()

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let appsCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero,collectionViewLayout: layout)
        return collectionView
    }()
    func setUpCollectionView(){
        backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        addSubview(appsCollectionView)
        appsCollectionView.delegate = self
        appsCollectionView.dataSource = self
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        print("sizeForItem is called")
        return CGSizeMake(100, 100)
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print("cellForItem is called")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```

hope someone will help

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer:**

Your forgot to register the cell to be used by the second collectionview:

```
appsCollectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
```

And second, set a valid frame for the viewcontroller:

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: 300, height: 200)
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

---

You might be confusing several concepts here. Why is your cell implementing *UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource* ? If you don't care about a clean architecture yet and just want to test things out, make your CollectionView's container viewcontroller implement said protocols (Could be a generic VC or subclass like UICollectionViewController).

What you are calling **HistoryCollectionViewCell** should be **HistoryCollectionViewController** and sublcass UIViewController or UICollectionViewController instead of UICollectionViewCell.

Those are separate responsibilities. You might want to check Github for examples or Apple's UIKit doc (e.g: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate). Or some tutorials online: https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started

```
class HistoryCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    // TODO: Refactor

    // Implement required methods
}


class HistoryCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    // Implement required methods
}
```

Comment: Because i want to add a UICollectionView inside a UICollectionViewCell so I can register it in another UICollectionView. I followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17729582/uicollectionview-in-a-uicollectionviewcell

Comment: My bad. Change collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero,...) to a valid frame

Comment: Don't take my word for it but I'd say the CollectionView doesn't reload it's data if both width and height are zero. Hence the data source functions aren't called.